# Base64 SVG images

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, svg, base64

I cannot get a base64 data URI for and SVG to appear as an image.

I tried an `<img>` and a `<canvas>` and for neither one does the SVG show up.

```js
var url = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa('<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"/></svg>');

document.getElementById('image').src = url;

var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.src = url;
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas, img {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" width="200" height="200">

<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

What doesn't the SVG show up?

Answer (score 17):

When embeding svg like this, remember to set `xmlns` for the `svg`:

```
var url = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + 
           btoa('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"/></svg>');
```

If there is any `xlink` prefix used in your svg elements, you should also add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`